# Where is the Audacity plugin folder?

Tags: pop-os, plugin, audacity

I'm trying to install some synths on audacity. I'm running PopOS 20.14. The audacity documentation says you should install plugins to `/Library/Application Support/audacity.` I cannot find this folder on my machine though.

I did find an audacity folder in the `lib` folder but that has no plugin folder so I'm again wondering if this is where I should be pasting the VST plugins?

Comment: Ubuntu : /usr/share/audacity/plug-ins/ https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/audacity-data/filelist

Comment: @KnudLarsen mind posting that as an answer. would like to upvote and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is the Audacity plugin folder?

Pop!_OS is Ubuntu based, please see this Ubuntu example https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/audacity-data/filelist
→

```
/usr/share/audacity/plug-ins/
```

Ref. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=audacity&searchon=names